# How to organize Network on GCP Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a kubernetes cluster on GCP, but I dont get the option to select "Network shared by me" when creating cluster. I can only choose the Network within the project, but I want to add networks from another project on GCP.

Is there any ways I can add "Network that is shared with me" in the Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster that uses a shared VPC. The steps are too large to post as an answer. There are several restrictions, such as you must have an organization.

This document will show you how:

[Setting up clusters with shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc)

Comment: Another solution is to perform VPC Peering and to have IP ranges that "belong to" another VPC (in your project or in another project).